# How to remove all the divs inside the $widget of a views exposed filter?

Tags: 7, theming, views

I need to remove all the divs inside the $widget of a views exposed filter. I need only the single form fields without any html around it.

I don't know PHP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the modules directory and look for the 'views' module.

There is a 'theme' folder within this.

In the theme folder, copy the 'views-exposed-form.tpl.php' file to your theme.

You can then edit the template as you require.

Note, when you copy a file like this you will want to clear caches for this to work.

*****UPDATE*****

To edit specific components of the form I suggest you override the following function in your themes template.php file.

```
template_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars)
```

This can also be found in the views module folder 'theme.inc'.

Comment: This file I'm currently editing. But contains the <?php print $widget->widget; ?> which outputs the whole form. And I need to edit this form WITHIN the $widget.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to simply output the input fields without any other html? Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: It isn't that simple I'm afraid. Each form component is constructed individually through the theme function. You need to strip it down by overriding these particulars.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is simple override your own theme page for the expose filter views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php to you theme template folder e.g.

views-exposed-form--view_name--machine_name.tpl.php

Example: views-exposed-form--latest_nodes--page.tpl.php

and remove which  you wold like to or adding your own.

Answer (score -2):

You can also do easy css tricks :

```
.class-of-elements-you-want-to-hide {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to remove them, not how to hide them. The other answers are correct, even if they cannot be as much specific as the OP wished.